# Scaling opencv matrix of type CV_8UC1 gives zeroes and ones

Tags: c++, opencv

I am attempting to scale a grayscale image of type `8UC1` by `1.0f/255`,
by the following operation

```
image.convertTo(image,CV_32F,1.0f/255,0);  //convert and scale
```

After inspecting the output of the above, I find that all values are too close to zero. For instance, at a point where the value should be `0.2784`, I'm getting `1.23417e-06`.

So, I tried to see if I could undo the scaling and get the input back i.e. multiplying the result from above by 255, using

```
cv::imwrite("undo_scaling.jpg",image*255); //rescale and write to disk
```

strangely, the input image can be reconstructed.
Where am I going wrong with the scaling operation?

EDIT

The following is my attempt to preprocess an image. That involves the followings steps

1. Apply a mask
2. Crop the result
3. Finally, scale the pixel values by 255

I use the following code:

```
cv::Mat maskCrop(std::string imageName, std::string maskName)
{
    cv::Mat image,mask,final_image;
    image = cv::imread( imageName, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    mask = cv::imread( maskName,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    cv::resize(image, image, mask.size());  // make the size of mask and image same

    cv::bitwise_and(image, mask, final_image); //Apply mask

    // define rectangular window for cropping
    int offset_x = 1250;  // top left corner, for cropping
    int offset_y = 1550;

    cv::Rect roi;
    roi.x = offset_x;
    roi.y = offset_y;
    roi.width = 550;
    roi.height = 650;

    // Crop the original image to the defined ROI //

    cv::Mat crop = dstImage(roi);
    crop.convertTo(crop,CV_32F,1.0f/255,0); 

    return crop;
}
```

Below is the input image:

[image: original image]

The following is the mask to be applied on it:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "scale"? convert the color range from 0-255 to 0-1?Have you tried just `image.convertTo(image,CV_32F);`?

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Yes I want all the pixel values to be between 0 and 1, hence I divide the matrix by 255. `image.convertTo(image,CV_32F);` doesn't seem to work

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem, but when I want to convert images, I use http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor

Comment: @Micka I changed the type to `CV_32F` according to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45393585/3620605

Comment: how did you "inspect the output"?

Comment: @Micka `image.at<double>(x_position,y_position)`. I also tried importing the output of `image.convertTo(image,CV_32F,1.0f/255,0); ` in python and compared with the output same operation, i.e. division by `255`, on input to the code in question. I got the expected values in python.

Comment: 32F is float, not double

Comment: @Micka Made that change, still getting `0` at positions where it should be close to `1`

Comment: provide sample image and full code please

Comment: the resize performs a linear interpolation. Could this explain "errors" in asumed pixel values? Can you try INTER_NN instead?

Comment: @Micka like this `cv::resize(image, image, mask.size(),0,0,cv::INTER_NEAREST )`?

Comment: Yes, should be righr

Comment: @Micka That didn't change the output. Am I doing the masking right with `cv::bitwise_and(image, mask, final_image)`